# Displaying a List of Documents Located in External HTML Files With Angular 12

Tags: angular

With Angular 12, I need to display a list of 160 documents that will be located in external HTML files. I manage to display the content of the external files with a mouse click (see example 1 on StackBlitz). However, it doesn't work in the case of displaying all the documents on a single page (see example 2 on StackBlitz) with a `*ngFor` loop. The contents appear in the following form: `[object, Object]`. I can't find the right method to display the contents as in the first example.

#### Example 1: Displaying external HTML files with a mouse click

The texts appear on the page.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7dmzfo

#### Example 2: Displaying external HTML files with a `*ngFor` loop

The texts do not appear on the page. However, the HTML code appears in the console.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tf43k6

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYVZY.jpg) |
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3p5u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend a way, easy to understand.

The first thing is to subscribe to the first observable, to retrieve your information.

Once we retrieve the information, we are going to add a 'document' property that will contain the observable of the call to retrieve the html.

Here is an [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bsjvf6)

- Do not use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, until you are very clear when and how to use it
- Be careful with making calls to observables from the html

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain how to proceed in this case.